# How do I adjust standard errors in a research study in which the control group is constructed via matching with replacement?

Tags: regression, clustering, sampling

I have a treatment sample of 200 firms.  I'm using propensity score matching to pair each treatment observation with one control (sampling with replacement, in order to minimize bias associated with poor matches).  This results in a sample of only 102 unique control firms (many of them are matched to multiple treatment observations).  My final sample consists of 400 observations, approximately 100 of which are duplicates.  My question is, what's the proper way to adjust my standard errors in a regression framework to account for the (complete) lack of independence in these duplicate observations?

Comment: Why would there be bias introduced by matching with replacement? What effects estimator are you using? Also, if possible, you may consider using covariate matches as well as propensity score matching.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think there is any justifiable way to compute the standard errors. The bootstrap appears to be a commonly used method, but Abadie and Imbens (2008 Econometrica) paper demonstrated the problems the bootstrap runs into. For a method as complicated as PS matching, I am not entirely sure 100 is a sufficiently large sample size to give you the asymptotically normal distribution.

Comment: If balance is good, and covariate matching is used as well as propensity score matching, the sample is plenty large enough for non-parametric estimators such as the Wilcoxon's sign-rank test. With the non-parametric estimator, the confidence interval coverage will be correct. An additional advantage of this approach is that sensitivity to the random assignment assumption can be tested with Rosenbaum bounds. See Paul Rosenbaum's _Observational Studies_ or _Design of Observational Studies_, the latter being an easier introduction.

Comment: I think my coefficient estimates should be unbiased, I'm just concerned about my t-statistics.  Are non-parametric estimators, such as the Wilcoxon sign-rank test or median regressions, less affected by correlation due to duplicate observations?

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, I don't think there is any justifiable way to compute the standard errors. The bootstrap appears to be a commonly used method, but Abadie and Imbens (2008 Econometrica) paper demonstrated the problems the bootstrap runs into. For a method as complicated as PS matching, I am not entirely sure 100 is a sufficiently large sample size to give you the asymptotically normal distribution. – StasK

If balance is good, and covariate matching is used as well as propensity score matching, the sample is plenty large enough for non-parametric estimators such as the Wilcoxon's sign-rank test. With the non-parametric estimator, the confidence interval coverage will be correct. An additional advantage of this approach is that sensitivity to the random assignment assumption can be tested with Rosenbaum bounds. See Paul Rosenbaum's Observational Studies or Design of Observational Studies, the latter being an easier introduction. – Jason Morgan

Comment: I've copied these comments by @StasK and JasonMorgan as a community wiki answer because the comments are, more or less, answers to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

Comment: Also h/t to @JasonMorgan (couldn't tag both in the same comment)